# Create incremental/differential backups in ProgressDB

Tags: backup, mirroring, progress-database

Is there a way to create incremental/differential backups in ProgressDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look here for the Progress docs: http://communities.progress.com/pcom/docs/DOC-16074

The manual you're looking for is the "Database Administration", and search for "incremental backups"

Comment: Have you got the solution? I need to create incremental backup in postgresql.

Comment: Postgresql is a different db platform.

Comment: What does that mean? Is there any way to create the incremental backups of postgresql database?

Comment: This question pertains to Progress Software databases - postgresql is a different technology and you need to ask your question where people knowledegable in such things congregate